# SICP Accumulate function

Tags: scheme, sicp

In *Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs* (SICP) [Section 2.2.3](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-15.html#%_sec_2.2.3) several functions are defined using:

```
(accumulate cons nil 
  (filter pred
         (map op sequence)))
```

Two examples that make use of this operate on a list of the fibonacci numbers, `even-fibs` and `list-fib-squares`.

The accumulate, filter and map functions are defined in section 2.2 as well. The part that's confusing me is why the authors included the `accumulate` here. `accumulate` takes 3 parameters:

- A binary function to be applied
- An initial value, used as the rightmost parameter to the function
- A list to which the function will be applied

An example of applying accumulate to a list using the definition in the book:

```
    (accumulate cons nil (list 1 2 3))
    => (cons 1 (cons 2 (cons 3 nil)))
    => (1 2 3)
```

Since the third parameter is a list, `(accumulate cons nil some-list)` will just return `some-list`, and in this case the result of `(filter pred (map op sequence))` is a list.

Is there a reason for this use of `accumulate` other than consistency with other similarly structured functions in the section?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm certain that those two uses of `accumulate` are merely illustrative of the fact that "consing elements to construct a list" can be treated as an accumulative process in the same way that "multiplying numbers to obtain a product" or "summing numbers to obtain a total" can.  You're correct that the accumulation is effectively a no-op.

(Aside:  Note that this could obviously be a more useful operation if the output of `filter` and input of `accumulate` was not a list; for example, if it represented a lazily generated sequence.)

Comment: It also seems to be intentionally trying to copy the structure of even-fibs here: http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-15.html#%_idx_1724 to illustrate the parallels.

Comment: It's also important to note that if you continue in scheme, a standard library foldr might be able to handle different forms of sequences beyond lists, and if you want the result to be a list, then cons-ing might be appropriate. (That's the only other case I can think of that you might want to do this sort of thing.)

Comment: Ah, that makes sense, both that non-list sequences may be used, and that this is demonstrating a kind of mechanical transformation of the earlier even-fibs function. Thank you both, this has been bugging me since I read it earlier this week.

Comment: just to clarify, "the accumulation [*there, with `(accumulate cons nil ...)`*] is effectively a no-op". But under `(let ((cons +) (nil 0))`,  `(accumulate cons nil ...)` would be something completely different.